# Unable to create site collection using Site Template in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a site on Office 365. 
I have saved these site as a template.

After that I'm creating new site using that template, but I got an error **This file may not be moved, deleted, renamed, or otherwise edited.**

I have tried to create site using PowerShell script and Browser also, still the same error.

Please suggest something.

Comment: did you try deleting the template and recreating it?